# Rails Time Zone and cron scheduling

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I have an AWS server that runs daily cron jobs reporting on our user base. I want to ensure my report is run for the full day the previous day in MST. Currently I use this as the code for the data quering

```
Time.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day).yesterday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone('MST)..Time.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day).yesterday.end_of_day.in_time_zone('MST)
```

I read it is bad practice to use Time.now as that is the system (UTC) time? I am wondering if what I am doing is a big no no or if there is a more efficient way?

thank you!

Comment: do you have any other questions or does my answer work for your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mountain Standard Time is 7 hours behind UTC, so when you capture all the data points from the day of July 22rd in MST, you want the UTC times to be from 7/22 at 7:00AM UTC to 7/23 at 7:00AM UTC.

I don't think your code is correct because you are calling `in_time_zone("MST")` after `beginning_of_day`.

When you run this code on a server that is on UTC, the evaluated times are different:

```
>> Time.new.yesterday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone('MST').utc
=> 2013-07-22 00:00:00 UTC
>> Time.new.in_time_zone("MST").yesterday.beginning_of_day.utc
=> 2013-07-22 07:00:00 UTC
```

Here is how you can determine the start and end times properly:

```
>> t = Time.new
=> 2013-07-23 19:45:10 +0000
>> start_time = t.in_time_zone("MST").yesterday.beginning_of_day
=> Mon, 22 Jul 2013 00:00:00 MST -07:00
>> end_time = t.in_time_zone("MST").yesterday.end_of_day
=> Mon, 22 Jul 2013 23:59:59 MST -07:00
```

When we convert the start and end times to UTC, we get the desired result.

```
>> start_time = t.in_time_zone("MST").yesterday.beginning_of_day.utc
=> 2013-07-22 07:00:00 UTC
>> end_time = t.in_time_zone("MST").yesterday.end_of_day.utc
=> 2013-07-23 06:59:59 UTC
```

Comment: This code will cause an error when the execution of `Time.new` in two places in your code overlaps with the moment of the change of the day.

Comment: @sawa - thanks for the comment.  Timezones always confuse me and I agree that calling Time.new in two places causes small errors.  However, I think calling `in_time_zone` after `beginning_of_day` is causing a much larger 7 hour error.  In any case, I updated the code per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but

```
Time.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day)
```

is definitely a terrible code fragment. For example, if the time lag between the execution time of `Time.now.year` and that of `Time.now.month` overlaps the moment of the change of the year, then the time object created with the main `Time.new` will be neither of the two moments. If you want to get the current time, just do

```
Time.new
```

or

```
Time.now
```

If you are trying to create a time range calculated out of a single time, then whatever your code should be, create time only once:

```
t = Time.now
```

and use that in the rest of your code:

```
t.some_method..t.some_other_method
```

Comment: I am trying to get the start and end time of the previous day